# Twillio sdk having issue with react native

Tags: javascript, android, performance, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to integrate twillio SDK with a React-Native android app. But not able to communicate with any call. What is the issue in that SDK?

Comment: you can check this link below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39653677/how-to-integrate-twilio-in-react-native-for-android/39752727#39752727