# Twilio call is not working in iOS and Android in react-native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, twilio, twilio-click-to-call

i am trying to use [twilio client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client)  in react native app.
here is the link [Twilio repo](https://github.com/rogchap/react-native-twilio) after done all setup with react native twilio .when i am calling a number getting issue . i used all steps give in this link .
[image]

[tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] handler is not a function. (In 'handler(rtn)', 'handler' is undefined)
2016-09-27 11:00:57.857 [fatal]

[tid:com.facebook.react.RCTExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: handler is not a function. (In 'handler(rtn)', 'handler' is undefined). code is breaking **in twilio app in index.js**

```
addEventListener(type, handler) {
_eventHandlers[type].set(handler, NativeAppEventEmitter.addListener(
type, rtn => {
handler(rtn);
}
));
},
```

not able to get where is the issue . i tried to implement in my native base code its working fine so my server setup does not have any issue .but don't how to solve in react native . any one have any idea about the issue.
[image]

Comment: How do you call `Twilio.addEventListener`? You need to pass a function for the second argument.

Comment: I am not calling  like this Twilio.addEventListener('deviceDidStartListening', this.deviceDidStartListening());

Comment: _Not_? If it's a typo and you are calling like this, it's wrong. You have to do `Twilio.addEventListener('deviceDidStartListening', this.deviceDidStartListening);` You must not call the function but only pass the reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have fixed that issue .issue is not in twilio npm . issue about the setup iOS react native project.
now i have used this steps 
1-in `node_modules,react-native-twilio/ios and add RCTTwilio.xcodeproj to` your project.

```
2- Add libRCTTwilio.a to Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries
```

I have done mistake to call Twilio.addEventListener (),
its need `Twilio.addEventListener ('type of event', 'call a event hadler')`,

for example

```
Twilio.addEventListener('deviceDidReceiveIncoming', this._deviceDidReceiveIncoming);
```

Comment: Hey Sport, thanks for posting your fix here. Can we get you a Twilio shirt? Send an email to mspeir@twilio.com for details.

Comment: @MeganSpeir i have sent you mail . Please reply it .

Comment: I have responded just now :)

Comment: Yes @MeganSpeir got